# Cannot extend a list and take set() in a single step without Non-Iterable error

Tags: python, list, set, extend, iterable

I'm trying to manage a list of unique items that may (or may not) get additions with each iteration of a loop. Maybe they are just integers produced by doSomething(someData).

So with each iteration I call doSomething and want to add my results to a growing list...

```
   uniqs = []
   for md in mydata:
       newOnes = doSomething(md)                   # returns a list eg [3,2,3]
       uniqs = list(set(uniqs.extend(newOnes)))    # keep only uniquely new items
```

But It appears i can't do the extend and the set at the same time without an error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I can do it in two steps,

```
   uniqs = []
   for md in mydata:
       newOnes = doSomething(md)        # returns a list eg [3,2,3]
       uniqs.extend(newOnes)            # extend the list will all new items
       uniqs = list(set(uniqs))         # keep only unique items
```

but I'd have thought that line would be okay, as the extend() would occur before the set() would be applied.  Not sure why it isn't.

Can someone clarify why that is?

-Ross

Comment: `extend` returns `None`. You will need to do it in two steps.

Comment: You could use `uniqs = list(set(uniqs + newOnes))`

Comment: Oh of course. Duh. Thx for the note.

Comment: Is there a reason `uniqs` can't be a set?

Comment: ... or at the very least, not convert backwards and forwards between lists and sets on every iteration of the loop

Comment: To debug this, split `uniqs = list(set(uniqs.extend(newOnes)))` into multiple lines and assign intermediate results to separate variables. Then you can print out those variables to see what is going on.

Comment: Why are you using a list at all when you need unique items? Just declare `uniqs = set()` and avoid lists entirely. If you need a list, convert the set to a list after the loop...but that seems unnecessary since you can iterate over a set just like you do a list.

Comment: And what you really want is `uniqs.update(...)` inside the loop (having initialised it with `set()` as suggested). You could not use `+` between a set an a list, but `update` will be fine with a list argument because it iterates over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy for `uniqs` to be a set rather than a list, you can use `update` to iterate over the list and add any elements that do not already exist:

```
   uniqs = set()
   for md in mydata:
       newOnes = doSomething(md)
       uniqs.update(newOnes)
```

If required, you can convert it to a list at the end with `uniqs = list(uniqs)`.  The ordering will be undefined, but as you are already using a set as an intermediate in your calculation, this is already the case.

You could perhaps write the above as a one-liner using `functools.reduce`:

```
functools.reduce(set.union, (set(doSomething(md)) for md in mydata))
```

although the explicit loop is probably more readable.